# c++ normalize an array

Tags: c++, arrays, normalization

I need to normalize an array, I find the max value which can be any number. I have to output this number using cout and represent it as 'x' how ever many times. The catch is I can only have a max amount of 60 x's. If my max is 500 I need to display it as 60 'x' and normalize my whole array to that.The code i have written is below.

```
void RollDice() {  
int DieFace[6];
int Rolls = 0;
int Seed = 0;
int Random = 0; 
int i = 0; 
char X = 'x';

DieFace[0] = 0;
DieFace[1] = 0;
DieFace[2] = 0;
DieFace[3] = 0;
DieFace[4] = 0;
DieFace[5] = 0; 


cout << "Enter number of times dice will be rolled. "; //output to user
cin >> Rolls; //get rolls
cout << endl;


cout << "Enter desired seed number. "; //output to user
cin >> Seed; //get seed
cout << endl;
srand(Seed);


for (int i = 0; i < Rolls; ++i) { //loop for RNG
Random = 1 + rand() % 6;

// boolean to get Face
if (Random == 1)
    DieFace[0] = DieFace[0] + 1;
else if (Random == 2)
    DieFace[1] = DieFace[1] + 1;
else if (Random == 3)
    DieFace[2] = DieFace[2] + 1;
else if (Random == 4)
    DieFace[3] = DieFace[3] + 1;
else if (Random == 5)
    DieFace[4] = DieFace[4] + 1;
else if (Random == 6)
    DieFace[5] = DieFace[5] + 1;
} 

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
cout << i + 1 << " Was Rolled: " << DieFace[i] << " Times." << endl;
}
cout << endl;

int Max = std::max({DieFace[0], DieFace[1], DieFace[2], DieFace[3], DieFace[4], DieFace[5] });   // find max value
```

Comment: [OT] You may simplify your `else if` by `DieFace[Random - 1]++;`

Comment: To normalize, you have to use `float`/`double`, else you will have only 0/1 in your int array.

Comment: @Jarod42 so simply changing it to double DieFace[6] would solve that? Then how would I normalize the array.

Comment: Please specify clearly that you want to print out the largest some as a factor of 60 and then print that factor out as 'x's literally. So for example if max=500, int factor = 500/60 = 8, for (int i=0; i< factor; ++i){ std::cout << "x "; }; std::cout << std::endl; which outputs "x x x x x x x x"

Answer (score 2):

get the highest amount of DieFace, if it's higher than your maximum, you have to scale em down (e.g.like this):

```
    int Max=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (DieFace[i]>Max) Max = DieFace[i];
    }
    for ( int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        cout << i << ":" ;
        int numHashes = DieFace[i];
        if (Max > 60) {
            numHashes = DieFace[i]*60/Max;
        }
        for (int j=0;j<numHashes;j++)
            cout << "#";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Say that your `Max` is 500. If you multiply that by 60 and then divide by 500, the result is precisely 60. If you have another value that's half of max (250), multiplying by 60 gives 15000 and then dividing by 500 gives **30**.

So the simple solution is: Multiply **all** outcomes by the **desired** maximum, and then divide by the **actual** maximum.

You don't need `double`, even though a comment claims so. `500*60` cannot overflow. It might be wise to use a `long` though, because using `int` is cutting it rather close. `600*60` might overflow an int (>32767) but a `long`  goes to 2 billion.

Comment: @siphr: No, I'm pretty sure I'm correct. You want to print 60 x's. It doesn't even make sense to print 8.3 x's. (The closest I can get is 8.5: `xxxxxxxx>` ;) )

Comment: Yes I believe you are right, I think the question could do with some clarification.